# Why is my class undefined at runtime. Javascript module pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, module-pattern

When i run my application i get: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined"
The alert in the document reasdy function runs, so i know jQuery is loaded at that point. But i don't know why Task is undefined.

This is in a MVC5 application, and running jQuery 1.10.2

Please help, jsFiddle works fine, and JsHint shows no errors.

```
    var Task = (function () {

    var initialize = function () {
        console.log($);
        bindEvents();
    };
    var postFilter = function () {
        console.log("clicked");
        var postData = {
            UserID: $('#user_select').val,
            TaskTypeID: $('#taskTypeSelect').val,
            TaskStatusID: $('#status_select').val,
            PriorityID: $('#priority_select').val
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Tasks/_AllTaskView",
            data: postData,
            success: function (response) {
                $('#results').html(response);
            }

        });
    };

    var bindEvents = function () {
        $('#submit_filter').on('click', postFilter);
    };

    return
    {
        init : initialize

    };

})();

$(document).ready(function () {
    alert()
    Task.init();
});
```

Comment: I am upvoting simply because I had no idea that `return` does not allow its value starting on subsequent lines (something every JS coder should be made aware of) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the curly brace of your `return` on the same line as `return`.

Instead of:

```
return
{
    init : initialize

};
```

Do this:

```
return {
    init : initialize
};
```

JavaScript has automatic semi-colon insertion which will automatically end the return statement before it hits the curly brace.

Comment: My bad (stupid inconsistent language.. give me C# any day ) - comment removed. Hey, it encouraged 3 other upvotes... don't complain :)

Comment: As a completely useless side note, this one works too: http://jsfiddle.net/3s6n4d5y/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here try this:

```
return{ init : function(){
                 initialize();
               }
      }
```